# Avoiding columns from groupby clause

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Here I need to avoid these 2 columns from the group by clause where it returns more number of records comparing with my expected value.

Actually the query result from `st.cnt` returns 3 records but when we run as `SP`, am getting double as expected.

*st_cnt.COUNT_FILES,

 st_cnt.COUNT_SCANS,*

```
SELECT table1.DA_SEC,
  table1.DA_REG,
  table1.PROJ,
  table1.SOL,
  table1.SCAN_YEAR_MON,
  to_char(TO_DATE(table1.SCAN_YEAR_MON, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY'),
  to_char(TO_DATE(table1.SCAN_YEAR_MON, 'YYYY-MM'), 'MM'),
  COUNT(DISTINCT table1.ISSUE_ID),
  COUNT(DISTINCT table1.USERNAME),
  COUNT(DISTINCT table1.PATH),
  st_cnt.COUNT_FILES,
  st_cnt.COUNT_SCANS,
  sum(unq_Pro.HIGH_CNT),
  sum(unq_Pro.MEDIUM_CNT),
  sum(unq_Pro.LOW_CNT),
  sum(SUPPR_HIGH) - sum(UNSUPPR_HIGH),
  sum(SUPPR_MEDIUM) - sum(UNSUPPR_MEDIUM),
  sum(SUPPR_LOW) - sum(UNSUPPR_LOW),
  CURRENT_DATE
FROM table1
JOIN
  (SELECT PROJ, SOL, SCAN_YEAR, SCAN_MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT PATH) COUNT_FILES, COUNT(DISTINCT SCAN_ID) COUNT_SCANS FROM table2 GROUP BY PROJ, SOL, SCAN_YEAR, SCAN_MONTH) st_cnt
ON st_cnt.PROJ = table1.PROJ--AND st_cnt.SOL = table1.SOL
GROUP BY table1.DA_SEC, table1.DA_REG, table1.PROJ, table1.SOL, table1.SCAN_YEAR_MON, st_cnt.COUNT_FILES, st_cnt.COUNT_SCAN;
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time using With Clause can be really helpful in these type of scenarios. Here is the ask tom thread that discusses With clause 
[Ask Tom Link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9534179900346111521) also a useful link on sub query factoring using with clause here [Sub Query Factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause)

It also helps us to know what the data for table 1 looks like in this case so we can test the answer. But with the information you shared something like this could help you

```
WITH TAB1_DATA AS (
SELECT table1.DA_SEC,
 table1.DA_REG,
 table1.PROJ,
 table1.SOL,
 table1.SCAN_YEAR_MON,
 to_char(TO_DATE(table1.SCAN_YEAR_MON, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY'),
 to_char(TO_DATE(table1.SCAN_YEAR_MON, 'YYYY-MM'), 'MM'),
COUNT(DISTINCT table1.ISSUE_ID),
COUNT(DISTINCT table1.USERNAME),
COUNT(DISTINCT table1.PATH),
sum(unq_Pro.HIGH_CNT),
sum(unq_Pro.MEDIUM_CNT),
sum(unq_Pro.LOW_CNT),
sum(SUPPR_HIGH) - sum(UNSUPPR_HIGH),
sum(SUPPR_MEDIUM) - sum(UNSUPPR_MEDIUM),
sum(SUPPR_LOW) - sum(UNSUPPR_LOW),
CURRENT_DATE
  FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.DA_SEC, table1.DA_REG, table1.PROJ, table1.SOL, table1.SCAN_YEAR_MON
)
 SELECT TD.* ,  st_cnt.COUNT_FILES,st_cnt.COUNT_SCANS FROM TAB1_DATA TD ,
(SELECT PROJ, SOL, SCAN_YEAR, SCAN_MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT PATH) COUNT_FILES, 
COUNT(DISTINCT SCAN_ID) COUNT_SCANS FROM table2 GROUP BY PROJ, SOL, SCAN_YEAR, 
SCAN_MONTH) st_cnt
WHERE st_cnt.PROJ = TD.PROJ;
```

Comment: Still  the records are splitting into more counts

Comment: Also,it's a stored procedure where we are inserting into a target table. How do we refer a select with "WITH" clause in a stored procedure.